# jQuery TableSorter Plugin error : cannot read property '1' of undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to use the jquery table sorter plugin but I am getting error when I try to sort the table.

This is the error message:

```
cannot read property '1' of undefined
```

This is my html code:

```
<table id='tweetResult' class="tablesorter" style="width:500px;">
 <thead>
    <th>Photo</th>
    <th>Name</>
    <th>Status</th>
    <th>Place Name</th>
    <th>Coordinate</th>
    <th>Created At</th>
  </thead>
  <tbody>

  </tbody>
</table>
```

The tbody content is in js format:

```
    $(document).ready(function(){ 
    $("#tweetResult").tablesorter(); 
}); 

(function(){
    var location = new Array();
    var query = '%23CM0655';
    var url = "search.php";
    $.post(url, {query:query}, function(tweets){
        console.log(tweets);
        $("#tweetResult tbody").html("");
        var geoEnabled = false;
        var placeName = "";
        var countryName = "";

        for(var i=0; i<tweets.statuses.length; i++){
            var row = $("<tr></tr>");
            var img = $("<td><img src='" + tweets.statuses[i].user.profile_image_url + "' class='tweetpic'/></td>");
            row.append(img);
              // row.append($("<td></td>").html(tweets.statuses[i].user.screen_name));

            row.append($("<td></td>").html(tweets.statuses[i].user.screen_name));
            row.append($("<td></td>").html(tweets.statuses[i].text + "<br/>"));
            geoEnabled = tweets.statuses[i].user.geo_enabled;
            if(geoEnabled){
                placeName = tweets.statuses[i].place.name;
                countryName = tweets.statuses[i].place.country;
                if(placeName != null){
                    row.append($("<td></td>").html(placeName + "," + countryName + "<br/>"));
                }
                row.append($("<td></td>").html("Location: " + tweets.statuses[i].place.bounding_box.coordinates[0][0][0] + ", " + 
                    tweets.statuses[i].place.bounding_box.coordinates[0][0][1] + "<br/>"));
                row.append($("<td></td>").html(tweets.statuses[i].created_at));
            }
            $("#tweetResult tbody").append(row)

        }
    });

    setTimeout(arguments.callee, 60000);
})();
```

This is the console.log(tweets) output:

```
Object
search_metadata
:
Object
statuses
:
Array[10]
__proto__
:
Object
```

Can someone tell me how to fix this error. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

i solved it by adding a timeout function

```
setTimeout(function(){
   $('table').tablesorter();
}, 10000);
```